# Can a Variant property have default value?

Tags: delphi, properties, default-value, variant

I've written a component who has a `Variant` property for which I would like to set a default value.

```
TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
private
  FVariantValue : Variant;
published
  property VariantValue : Variant read FVariantValue write FVariantValue default False;
end;
```

On compilation, I get the following error on the `VariantValue` property line:

> E2026 Constant expression expected

Doing the same thing with a `Boolean` property doesn't cause any kind of error.

I read a little bit of [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Default_Property_Values) but I didn't find nothing about `Variant` properties default values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be careful here.  The `default` directive does not do anything to set the value of the property itself.  It only affects whether or not the value is explicitly saved in the `.dfm` file.  If you specify a `default` value for a property you still have to ensure that the constructor initializes the backing field to that value.

[Properties : Storage Specifiers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties#Storage_Specifiers)

> When saving a component's state, the storage specifiers of the component's published properties are checked. If a property's current value is different from its **default** value (or if there is no **default** value) and the **stored** specifier is **True**, then the property's value is saved. Otherwise, the property's value is not saved.
>
> **Note**: Property values are not automatically initialized to the default value. That is, the default directive controls only when property values are saved to the form file, but not the initial value of the property on a newly created instance.

This is just a hint to the component streaming system that it doesn't need to store this value explicitly in the `.dfm` - your part of the contract is to ensure that you actually initialize the backing field to that value. The appropriate place to do this type of initialization is in the component's constructor:

```
constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FVariantValue := False;
end;
```

That said, `False` is a boolean, not a variant, so it cannot be used as a constant expression of `Variant` type.  Since a variant is a complex type it cannot be expressed as a single constant and, therefore, cannot have a `default` property.

Per Remy, if you want to ensure that the variant is not saved in the `.dfm` file when the backing variant is `False`, you can use the `stored` directive with a parameterless method which returns `False` when the variant evaluates to a boolean `False`.  For example :

```
 property VariantValue : Variant read FVariantValue write FVariantValue stored IsVariantValueStored;
```

where

```
function TMyComponent.IsVariantValueStored : Boolean;
begin
  Result := not VarIsType(FVariantValue, varBoolean);
  if not Result then
    Result := FVariantValue;
end;
```

Comment: For purposes of DFM streaming, if you don't want the property to be stored in the DFM when the Variant contains a False value, you can use the `stored` specifier instead of the `default` specifier, where `stored` refers to a parameterless method that returns False if the Variant contains a False value and returns True otherwise.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Very clever - not sure that's what OP actually wants, but I've updated with that example.

Answer (score 4):

Variant properties cannot have default values.

Comment: Your answer is not enogh , when you said cannot have default values please please try to explain why , that will make sense.

Comment: Because the designers took that decision. I can't say why though. Only they can.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is set

```
FVariantValue := false;
```

in the constructor or `procedure AfterConstruction; override;`